# Thread pool understanding problem

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, threadpool

I'm trying to figure out a way how to align tasks in a thread pool. 
I have 4 ( parallel ) threads and at the beginning ( of each thread execution step ) 10 tasks. My first attempt was to measure the time of each task, and based on that time find the best combination of tasks in threads to get the best possible result. I'm attempting to write a parallel game engine based on this article http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/designing-the-framework-of-a-parallel-game-engine/

The problem is that my 'solution' does not work. Are there any more ways to align tasks?

(The project is in c++)

Comment: What language is this in?  If Java, you can use the new [Phaser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) class in JDK 7 to keep your threads in sync.

Comment: It would be much easier to use an existing framework, like TBB or PPL, to manage this.

Comment: It would, but i want to learn how it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out both smoke (their multithreaded processing tech demo engine) and nullstien from intels visual computing site, they both tackle thread pooling tasks (nullstien has two variants, a tbb based scheduler and a custom built one)

Answer (score 1):

To align tasks in parallel threads, use semaphores, events, mutexes.
Do not measure the time a task takes. Threads are executed at most randomly.
If you're executing 4 tasks in parallel threads, the first 2 may finish even before the second 2 begin.
Here is how to properly do it

```
void Thread1()
{
    task1();
    semaphore1.Release()
}

void Thread2()
{
    task2();
    semaphore1.WaitOne();
    task3();
}
```

this way, task3 will be always executed after task1 finishes